# Bash: For Filename do

Tags: bash, filenames

Hi I'm not used to do things in Bash, so I'm having some problems:

My goal is to look for special files in a folder, and if found generate some other files with the same filenames, but different extension.

Something like:

```
For Files-that-are-called-"SysBackup*.Now" 
do
  NewFileName = ChangeFileExt(FoundFilename),BK
  GenerateNewfile(NewFileName)
done
```

The above is of course dummycode, I won't bother you with the code I have done, as it is not working :-)

So the goal should be:

If the folder contains
Sysbackup123.now and Sysbackup666.now, I will end up with the files Sysbackup123.bk and Sysbackup666.bk

Thank you for any help

Michael

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fairly straightforward:

```
for a in Sysbackup*.now;
do
  [ -f $a ] && touch $(basename $a .now).bk ;
done
```

Comment: Bash also allows stripping characters from the end of a string with *%*.  And you *probably* should get in the habit of quoting filenames: **touch "${a%.now}.bk"**

Comment: Hmmm, one thing:

 for file in Sysbackup*.now;do
    echo "WTF?"
  done

The problem is that every time I run my script, the WTF? gets written to the screen, even though there is no Sysback.now file.I would guess (and I need) that the function only is running if there in fact IS a Sysbackup*.now file

Comment: @Reiler: if no file is matched, then the literal search pattern will be assigned to `a`. Thus you need to prefix the `touch` command with a test like `[ -e $F ] && ` or even more specific `[ -f $F ] && `. See my answer below for an example.

Comment: I added the check for the file before the `touch` command. (I did have that line in originally but removed it! Doh!)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the check if it was a file did the job

Comment: Reiler, remember to click the check-mark to this response, so that the system knows that it is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do the substitution. Bash has an equivalent to sed's `s/string1$/string2/` which uses the regex dollar sign to select the end of the pattern:

```
for a in Sysbackup*.Now;
do
  [ -f $a ] && touch "${a/%.Now/.BK}"
done
```

The percent sign matches at the end and a pound (#) matches at the beginning.

Comment: You need to use **.Now** in your first line: if you match files, they will end with **.now** not **.Now** as the OP used, and as you used in your variable pattern -- and as a consequence, you'd just *touch* the original file.

Comment: As I said to *ghostdog74* - this one reason I usually avoid the *substitute* pattern, and use the *remove/append* instead:  **${file%.Now}.BK** -- which will never be the same as the original filename.  I once did something like this: **grep "$PATTERN" "$a" > "${a/%.Now/.BK}"** -- and consequently lost all of my data.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it with `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in SysBackup*.now; do
  if [ ! -e "$file" ]; then
    continue
  fi

  base=${file##*/}
  bk=${base%.now}.bk

  touch $bk
done
```

Comment: Although I don't believe it's particularly interesting, wouldn't the solution I'm using be faster as it doesn't require to fork and invoke `basename`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
for F in SysBackup*.Now; do
    [ -f $F ] && touch $(echo "$F" | sed 's/Now$/BK/')
done
```

This uses [`echo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) to pass the filenames to [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), which changes the postfix string `"Now"` to `"BK"`. [`touch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) creates the file, if it does not exist yet. The new file will be empty. The test `[ -f $F ]` ensures that only files (not directories or symlinks) are considered.

Alternatively, you can use [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find). An example using [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename), as demonstrated in [Stephen Darlington's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776073/bash-for-filename-do/1776096#1776096):

```
find . -type f -iname "SysBackup*.Now" -exec sh -c "touch \$(basename '{}' .Now).BK" \;
```

Note that in both examples it is important to place quotes around the filenames, to ensure proper handling of filenames with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

here's another way, if you don't want to use for loop and testing whether its a file or not

```
find /path -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "Sysbackup*now" | while read file
do
  touch "${file/%.now/.bK}"
done
```

Comment: Not sure I like using **find** simply to avoid the no-match problem, but whatever.  However, you need a dot in your *-name* argument, otherwise a file named **Sysbackup-before-snow** will be found and, since it does not end in ".now" the filename will be given, unchanged, to the **touch** program.  This one reason I usually avoid the *substitute* pattern, and use the *remove/append* instead:  **${file%.now}.bk** -- which will never be the same as the original filename (at least it will append a ".bk").